# I have problems with moving the address to left align and it still didn't work at all

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[image]

I've tried to move the address to far left corner but it didn't work at all.

> This is what I tried to move the address to far left corner but so
>   far it didn't work at all.

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

  <!-- Column address below -->

  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="example">
          Baylight Construction LLC 1022 boyle street
          <br>Tel- (232)233-4323 Fax-(232)233-2323
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.nav a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 40px 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
}
img {
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
}
.fixed-nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 165px;
  background-color: green;
}

//I've tried that class example and row and none of didn't move to
//far left corner
.example {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.row {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Create live https://jsfiddle.net example with issue

Answer (score 1):

I has try out this, try this and see [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/michael5119/k50ovpLf/9/)

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- Column address below -->
  <div class="col-md-6 row col-md-pull-1">

    Baylight Construction LLC 1022 boyle street
    <br>Tel- (232)233-4323 Fax-(232)233-2323

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code example i'm guessing you're trying to use bootstraps own classes to position the adress. In that case the problem you're having is not that your elements with the class "example" isn't positioning themselves to the left inside their containers.

It's that the **container** class you're using has a fixed-width depending on the width of the screen, aswell as being centered in the screen. In your case the container class will have a width of:

Screen: < 768px : Width of container: (auto)

Screen: ≥ 768px : Width of container: 750px

Screen: ≥ 992px : Width of container: 970px

Screen: ≥ 1200px : Width of container: 1170px

In order for your container to take up the full width of the screen change the **container** class to **container-fluid**, wich is bootstraps class for a full width container. 
Now instead of taking up a fixed width, the container will always take up 100% of the screens width, thus your adress bar will be placed to far left.

See your edited example
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/arkpuhdm/) or in the snippet down below.

```css
//I've tried that class example and row and none of didn't move to
//far left corner
.example {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.row {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">

  <!-- Column address below -->

  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="example">
          Baylight Construction LLC 1022 boyle street
          <br>Tel- (232)233-4323 Fax-(232)233-2323
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```